# Horizontally space out my checkboxes using css?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, margin, padding

I have a list of checkboxes that I'd like to have spaced out on a single horizontal line.

```
<div class="timesheet-daily-entry-fields-container">
        <input id="TimesheetMondayCheckbox" class="timesheet-daily-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
        <input id="TimesheetTuesdayCheckbox" class="timesheet-daily-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
        <input id="TimesheetWednesdayCheckbox" class="timesheet-daily-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
        <input id="TimesheetThursdayCheckbox" class="timesheet-daily-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
        <input id="TimesheetFridayCheckbox" class="timesheet-daily-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
        <input id="TimesheetSaturdayCheckbox" class="timesheet-daily-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
        <input id="TimesheetSundayCheckbox" class="timesheet-daily-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
 </div>
```

They display on the line, but I'd like to space them out more.

```
.timesheet-daily-checkbox {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

I'd rather not create a div around each input, is there an easier way?

Comment: Doesn't increasing the right margin in your `timesheet-daily-checkbox` class do it?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Well, I don't know. That's why I'm here.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pyRcz/. Do you have other code that might be interfering?

Comment: @j08691 posted your fiddle before I posted my fiddle!

Comment: Hmm well I guess there must be something interfering because I place exactly that and my checkboxes are not spaced enough. I have bootstrap, that wouldn't do anything though, would it?

Comment: Depending on the CSS sure it could.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I should have tried jsfiddle first, that was my bad.

Comment: Why is this question closed as too narrow?! With over 12k views on this question it clearly bothers many people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the left and right margin

```
margin: 10px 20px;
```

Comment: I removed all other stylings except for this but it didn't work.

Comment: Why remove the others? That was the one you needed to change. http://jsfiddle.net/2SXUH/

Comment: Well at first I didn't. It didn't work both ways but appears to be a separate issue.

Comment: Check the fiddle in my comment, it works fine. Something else in your code must be affecting it.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer as it is correct. In the end, I had to apply styles inline to override whichever other code was affecting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the CSS class on the containing element's class AND the input tag, like this:

```
.timesheet-daily-entry-fields-container input {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

That'll save you having to add a class to each input element. To space them out more, increase the margin.

Answer (score 0):

Wel you do not even have labels yet. Have you tried that? A label and some spaces would work wonders.

Comment: I was hoping to implement this without needing extra code for blank labels, but if that's the best method, I'll do it.

Comment: I was not implying you use blank labels at all. I was just assuming that eventually you need to give them some.

Comment: Still, you should not be adding spaces (non-breaking or normal) to create horizontal whitespace, the same as you should not use `<br>` tags to create vertical whitespace.  That is what margins and padding are for.