# Checkboxes and php and css

Tags: php, css, checkbox

Ok let me rephrase this a bit. I have a form in the form I have checkboxes they currently display vertically I need them to display horizontally. The form is wrapped in a section tag. I put the id tag of colorSwatches as , I've tried , I've tried  and for colorSwatches in the CSS I put display:inline-block. It did not work any variation. Here is the URL to see the page in question http://www.inertiastreak.com/serial_quilters/order.php

I have the following block of code:

```
<ul id="colorSwatches">
          <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['color[]'] == 'color[]') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red" />Red</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="orange" />Orange</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="yellow" />Yellow</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="green" />Green</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="blue" />Blue</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="purple" />Purple</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="pink" />Pink</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="brown" />Brown</li> 
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="black" />Black</li>                   
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="white" />White</li>                   
          </ul>
```

Right now the list of checkboxes show in a vertical line. I would like the checkbox and color to show up in a horizontal line. Every which variation of CSS I put in is not working at all. I have tried putting the id of colorSwatches as section#colorSwatches ul li {display:inline-block;} and it didn't work. The only way it worked was that I closed the form above the list of colors, then closed the section tag. Opened a new section tag and a new form tag and essentially created a second form, which was unneeded.

If someone could please advise how to go get a stack of input fields like the ones above to display in the inline-block fashion that would be great. UL and LI can be removed it doesn't matter  to me.

Btw the PHP shouldn't be changed.

Comment: does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981746/horizontally-space-out-my-checkboxes-using-css ?

Comment: nope. http://www.inertiastreak.com/serial_quilting/order.php Here is the page in question you will see the list of checkboxes towards the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Give class to li as class="li_color".

```
<ul id="colorSwatches">
              <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['color[]'] == 'color[]') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red" />Red</li>
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="orange" />Orange</li>
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="yellow" />Yellow</li>
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="green" />Green</li>
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="blue" />Blue</li> 
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="purple" />Purple</li> 
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="pink" />Pink</li>
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="brown" />Brown</li> 
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="black" />Black</li>                   
              <li class="li_color"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="white" />White</li>                   
          </ul>
```

Give the style to li_color as

```
#colorSwatches {width:100%;}
#colorSwatches .li_color { float:left; width:100px; }
```

If width is not enough, you can increase.

Comment: And how will that make the checkboxes appear in one row, left to right not top to bottom?

Comment: I dont know what is not working. It is working fine for me. You can reduce the width in #colorSwatches .li_color {float:left; width:70px} to show all the color in single line.

Comment: In your url  inertiastreak.com/serial_quilting/order.php - contact_order.css - Line no. 33 #contact-form input - given the input type checkbox width as 650px. Remove it or give .li_color input {width: 15px;}

Answer (score 1):

For the `ul` `li` listing make 100% width like

```
#colorSwatches{width:100%;float:left;}
#colorSwatches li{float:left;}
```

Refer this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q8q4a/)

Comment: And how will that make the checkboxes appear in one row, left to right not top to bottom?

Comment: When I added your code in it did not work. Please reference http://www.inertiastreak.com/serial_quilter/order.php for the actual page in question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

```
#colorSwatches li{
    display: inline;
}
#colorSwatches{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Ok so this semi worked. It was able to put the check boxes with the color next to it in a straight line, but it puts an enormous amount of space between the check box and the color and an enormous amount of space between the previous color and the next checkbox

Answer (score 0):

the best and easiest way is add this after every line :

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense

Comment: excuse me , set the float of checkboxes to left, and then put it after each line,