# how to align dynamically added checkboxes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 <h5>* Amenities </h5>
        @foreach (var l in (SelectList)ViewBag.Amenities )
     { 
       <input type="checkbox" class="Amenity" name="Amenities" value="@l.Value"         id="@l.Value" @l.Selected ? "checked='checked';" : @String.Empty   /> 
          <label for="l@(l.Value)">@l.Text</label>
     }
```

I have added these check-boxes using for loop. While rendering they are placed in separate lines. I want them to be aligned horizontally.

Comment: All else being equal, that will not result in them being placed on separate lines. Find the CSS that is changing that and edit it.

Comment: If they are vertically aligned, its because you have styled them that way. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bejt9048/) shows the default (no styling) is horizontal alignment. You have a `.css` file in your project that is overriding the default behavior. Use your browser tools to inspect the elements and adjust properties until you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this out :

```
@foreach (var l in (SelectList)ViewBag.Amenities )
     { 
       <input type="checkbox" class="Amenity" name="Amenities" value="@l.Value"         id="@l.Value" @l.Selected ? "checked='checked';" : @String.Empty   /> 
          <label style="display:inline" for="l@(l.Value)">@l.Text</label>
     }
```

This will place your labels inline with your checkboxes.

Hope this would help!

Thanks,
Swati

Comment: Very well done ! But why is it so that adding style to check- boxes or div did't work ?

Comment: Because here you need to make labels inline with your checkboxes. 

If in case you had to Place labels first and then Checkboxes next to your labels then You need to make your checkboxes display:inline.

like shown here:

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
  @foreach (var l in (SelectList)ViewBag.Amenities )
  { 
    <div style="display: inline">
       <input type="checkbox" class="Amenity" name="Amenities" value="@l.Value"         id="@l.Value" @l.Selected ? "checked='checked';" : @String.Empty   /> 
       <label for="l@(l.Value)">@l.Text</label>
    </div>
  }
```

Comment: You can also try 'display: inline-block'. If it doesn't work, you should look 'Amenity' class maybe some property in it block 'inline'.

Answer (score -1):

Try `inline:display-block` on each input element

Hope this help

Comment: No  bro It didn't work. I am getting a long line of check boxes aligned vertically which looks weird.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981746/horizontally-space-out-my-checkboxes-using-css)